# how to export .req file by using PEMWriter?

Tags: java, certificate, pem, writer

I've a request data but I don't know how to export this request data by using PEMWriter.

**My request data :**

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIBoDCCAQkCAQAwYDEQMA4GA1UEBhMHTXlhbm1hcjEKMAgGA1UECBMBdDEKMAgGA1UEBxMBdDEK
MAgGA1UEChMBdDEKMAgGA1UECxMBdDEKMAgGA1UEAxMBdDEQMA4GCSqGSIb3DQEJARYBdDCBnzAN
BgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAp8NqU0BHIlxzOWuoAtOcamm1cxlAr5Uz+wlx/KSxKR4p
0VqV1PdUVNVK2O7C1jy5VB+hXeNIlwo3BIlA6hdWtS33ynZxdUZ9BrHr6lELjd6T91q0yzbV/dQk
pR0KmycIOXgfqGF7PhZlGku+fI7wllI8n/oZvFnW/M4kSCnfEBcCAwEAAaAAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
BQUAA4GBADgOHimTuqjb+Vbt0ffuK9skIQFCoicfKV5vKPpU8Uxeji/RuQ7zQVoACYOcQ8O1Epof
Aq7vZFLXKlscFO/w4UKWGEix45JIFoc8a6rCVUQph8P8GLdQNofIWVXc2dgBe/yCqgD54bnQt1tX
GLciFlHU+Oa0Lxtdc+jIOzzvYe5P
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

I exported request data by using PEMWriter just like this.
**Code :**

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(txtRequest.getText()));
PEMWriter writer = new PEMWriter(bw2);                  
writer.writeObject(certificate);

writer.close();
bw.close();
```

But I've an error.

**Error : java.io.IOException: unknown object passed - can't encode.**

Please explain me. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of object is 'certificate'?

Answer (score 0):

First you are creating a BufferedWriter `bw` but using `bw2` as parameter to PEMWriter. I guess this is just a copy/paste error and does not matter.

What you use as parameter to the writeObject however does matter. In your case it should probably be an object of the class `java.security.cert.X509Certificate`.
The method does not accept parameters of type `javax.security.cert.X509Certificate` - the difference is the x in javax.

Take a look into the source code of Bouncy Castle PEMWriter to see what other kind of classes the method accepts.